Can't connect to MariaDB after enabling TLS on localhost
MariaDB 11.5.2 on Debian 12.
I've created certificates for my server, located in /etc/acme and mode 644 (owner root, group mysql)
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d $ cat 99-bsz.cnf 

[mysqld]

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
ssl_ca = /etc/ssl/certs/sectigo-ca.pem
ssl_cert = /etc/acme/hostname-fullchain.pem
ssl_key = /etc/acme/hostname-key.pem
tls_version = TLS1.3
#require-secure-transport = on # played with this oiption, nothing helps
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G

cat 50-client.cnf 

[client-mariadb]
ssl
ssl-verify-server-cert

But it does not work
$ mariadb -p -u root
Enter password: 
ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: Hostname verification failed

When I set
cat 50-client.cnf
[client-mariadb]
host= hostname.tld

mariadb -p works. So, It requires a valid FQDN, localhost or 127.0.0.1 is not enough. I can then check if TLS is enabled for my connection, and status says SSL: Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, cert is OK but REQUIRE SSL is not set for root.
> SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE ssl_type <> '';
+------------+----------------+
| User       | Host           |
+------------+----------------+
| user1      | X.Y.Z.W        |
| user2      | X.Y.Z.W        |
| user3      | X.Y.Z.W        |
+------------+----------------+

These are all remote users who shall require SSL. But why is SSL enforced for root, too?

A couple of things: when running  MySQL and derivatives on Unix hosts  localhost has a special meaning  "connect using a Unix socket file" and not "over TCP/IP with the IP-address 127.0.0.1" . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/connecting.html The fact that in error messages IP-addresses get displayed as after a reverse DNS lookup (i.e. 127.0.0.1 gets displayed as localhost) does not help troubleshooting.  So with regards to your second error message: check your GRANT table if access has been set up for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' and not only for 'root'@'localhost'.

Added this but still can't connect without specifying a FQDN from localhosat. Need to know how to disable SSL for connections from localhost/127.0.0.1.

Added more details. The hostname is required because TLS is enforced from localhost, too.
